# Prove that $f=g$

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, principal-ideal-domains, unique-factorization-domains

> Let $A=K[x]$ be the ring of polynomials over the field $K$.
>   Let $m\in A$ with $\deg(m)\ge1$, and let $I=(m)$ the principal ideal generated by $m$. Let $f,g \in A$ so that $\deg(f)<\deg(m)$ and $\deg(g)<\deg(m)$.
>
> Prove that if $f\equiv g\bmod I$ , then $f=g$. Conclude that the congruence classes $\bmod I$ are in bijective correspondence with the $f\in A$ so that $\deg(f)<\deg(m)$.
>
> Finally show who is $R[x] /(x^2+1)$.

My attempt so far: $f+I=g+I$ iff $f-g\in(m)$ iff $m\mid f-g$ iff $f-f'=am$ for some $a\in A$. But $A$ is a Euclidean domain (also a PID and UFD) so $\deg(m)\le \deg(f-g)$ but $\deg(f-g)\lt \deg(m)$ right? 
I don't know what to do from here but I think that $m$ should be zero. 
Any help or hints will be very appreciated.

Comment: I don't think it is good idea to use $\;f'\;$ to denote a polynomial **which is not  necessarily** the formal derivative of $\;f\;$ . It is rather confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you were close :

$$f\equiv g\pmod I\iff f-g=am\;\;\text{and}\;\;\deg(f-g)<\deg m\implies f-g=0$$

and you have the first part.

For the second part: write every element in $\;\Bbb R[x]/\langle x^2+1\rangle\;$, using the above, as

$$\;(ax+b)+I\;,\;\;I:=\langle x^2+1\rangle\;,\;\;a,b\in\Bbb R$$

Observe that, for example, $\;x\cdot x=x^2=-1\pmod I\;$ , and now realize the similarity we have here with the complex numbers...Finally, show $\;\Bbb R[x]/I\cong\Bbb C\;$

Comment: How did you conclude that f-g=0.  I can't see why

Comment: If $\;f-g=am\implies \deg(f-g)\ge\deg m\;$ ... **or** ... $\;f-g=0\;$ . In your notation, it follows that in fact $\;f-g=am\implies a=0\;$ . There's no other possibility for a polynomial  $\;h\;$ over a field to belong to an ideal generated by a polynomial whose degree is  **greater** than the degree of $\;h\;$